# Fancybox does not trigger when used in Master page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I want to display the search result in the Fancybox. The code works fine in the web form, but when i integrate with the master page, the fancy box is not opening. Please give me a solution!
I created two web forms, Default1.aspx and Default2.aspx
The code in the **Default1.aspx** is given below,

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
       <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#fancybox').fancybox({
                  autoDimensions: false,
                  height: 400,
                  width: 700,
                  type: "iframe"
              });
         });

     </script>
     <a id="fancybox" runat="server" style=" visibility: hidden "></a>
     <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
   </div>
</form>
</body>

**Default1.aspx.cs**

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["cargoNo"];
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        fancybox.Attributes["href"] = "~/Default2.aspx?cargoNo=" + TextBox1.Text.Trim();
        Literal1.Text = "<script> $(document).ready(function() {$(\"#fancybox\").trigger('click');});</script>";

        clear();
    }
    public void clear()
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "";
    }

}
```

In the Default2.aspx I added a Sql Datasource and used Gridview to display it.

When you enter the number in the text box and click button1. the serach will initiate and display the result in the fancybox. The above code is working great. 
When i added this to the Master page the Fancybox is not triggering. Twhen button is clicked, the page just refresh. All replies are appreciated. I am new to asp.net. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure You don't call a Jquery source in your Master Page, because I see you are calling Jquery on your `Default1.aspx`, since Jquery should be load once. Second, if you don't want your button make a Postback, add this to your button: `UseSubmitBehavior="False"`. Hope this help